# Why are the last 6 polygons not rendered in this html svg?

Tags: html, svg

There should be a row of 12 triangles (6 box spaces) but only 6 tris are actually rendered. When inspecting the svg, they do seem to be accounted for (they take up space on the screen) but they're still invisible. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

```css
  polygon{
   stroke-width:1;
  }
  .c1{
   fill:#222;
   stroke:#222;
  }
  .c2{
   fill:#111;
   stroke:#111;
  }
  .c3{
   fill:#000;
   stroke:#000;
  }
  .c4{
   fill:#333;
   stroke:#333;
  }
```

```html
<svg>
 <polygon class="c1" points="0,100 0,0, 100,0"/>
 <polygon class="c2" points="0,100 100,100, 100,0"/>

 <polygon class="c1" points="100,100 100,0, 200,0"/>
 <polygon class="c1" points="100,100 200,100, 200,0"/>

 <polygon class="c1" points="200,100 200,0, 300,0"/>
 <polygon class="c2" points="200,100 300,100, 300,0"/>

 <polygon class="c4" points="300,100 300,0, 400,0"/>
 <polygon class="c2" points="300,100 400,100, 400,0"/>

 <polygon class="c3" points="400,100 400,0, 500,0"/>
 <polygon class="c3" points="400,100 500,100, 500,0"/>

 <polygon class="c2" points="500,100 500,0, 600,0"/>
 <polygon class="c2" points="500,100 600,100, 600,0"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute to SVG.

```css
polygon{
   stroke-width:1;
  }
  .c1{
   fill:#222;
   stroke:#222;
  }
  .c2{
   fill:#111;
   stroke:#111;
  }
  .c3{
   fill:#000;
   stroke:#000;
  }
  .c4{
   fill:#333;
   stroke:#333;
  }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 100">
 <polygon class="c1" points="0,100 0,0, 100,0"/>
 <polygon class="c2" points="0,100 100,100, 100,0"/>

 <polygon class="c1" points="100,100 100,0, 200,0"/>
 <polygon class="c1" points="100,100 200,100, 200,0"/>

 <polygon class="c1" points="200,100 200,0, 300,0"/>
 <polygon class="c2" points="200,100 300,100, 300,0"/>

 <polygon class="c4" points="300,100 300,0, 400,0"/>
 <polygon class="c2" points="300,100 400,100, 400,0"/>

 <polygon class="c3" points="400,100 400,0, 500,0"/>
 <polygon class="c3" points="400,100 500,100, 500,0"/>

 <polygon class="c2" points="500,100 500,0, 600,0"/>
 <polygon class="c2" points="500,100 600,100, 600,0"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: What a facepalm. Thanks! Will accept once possible.